# Desire2Learn Valence API Creating and updating sections?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am working on integration with our university's SIS system and am stumbling a bit with the documentation related to creating and updating sections.  http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#Section.SectionData

I can use the route `PUT /d2l/api/lp/(version)/(orgUnitId)/sections/` to create a default section named Section 1 with section code sec1 however when I try to update it or add an additional section with the routes: `PUT /d2l/api/lp/(version)/(orgUnitId)/sections/(sectionId)` (with the sectionId retrieved from my previous PUT) or `POST /d2l/api/lp/(version)/(orgUnitId)/sections/`

I am using the following block for my json data:

```
{
  "Name": "Section 1d",
  "Code": "Dan 101",
  "Description": {
    "Text": "",
    "Html": ""
  }
}
```

What am I missing in the syntax?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your routes and your request are okay.  Only one small change with the route. You need to use the RichTextInput field that is described in the documentation [D2L Conventions](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/conventions.html)

Basically instead of:

```
"Description": {
   "Text": "",
   "Html": ""
}
```

You need:

```
"Description": {
   "Content": "",
   "Type": "" (Either Text or Html)
}
```

Comment: That was the problem.  Thank You!

Comment: Thanks! You said the same thing I did, but in many fewer words! 8)

Answer (score 1):

The way you use the Valence Learning Framework API to create sections for course offerings is idiosyncratic. Assume you start with a blank course, that has no descendant org units (no sections, no groups, nothing):

```
GET /d2l/api/lp/1.3/orgstructure/113459
> {"Name": "Extensibility 106",
   "Identifier": "113459", 
   "Type": {"Name": "Course Offering", 
            "Code": "Course Offering",
            "Id": 3},
   "Code": "EXT-106"}

GET /d2l/api/lp/1.3/orgstructure/113459/children
> []
```

**Initialize course with section properties**. The first thing you have to do is define the section properties for the course offering: what kind of sections do you want to create under the course offering? To create the section properties for the course offering, you use a SectionPropertyData block; here's one that says "I want this course to have 10 sections and to auto-enroll the students, randomly, into these sections" (`EnrollmentStyle` 2 corresponds to `NumberOfSectionsAutoEnrollment`):

```
{"AutoEnroll": true,
 "EnrollmentQuantity": 10,
 "EnrollmentStyle": 2,
 "RandomizeEnrollments": true}
```

Now, to initialize the course with these settings, and have the first default section(s) created, we **PUT** that block to this route:

```
PUT /d2l/api/lp/1.3/113459/sections/
> [{"SectionId":113460,
    "Name":"Section 1",
    "Description":{"Text":"","Html":""},
    "Enrollments":[]},
   ...
   {"SectionId":113469,
    "Name":"Section 10",
    "Description":{"Text":"","Html":""},
    "Enrollments":[]}
  ]
```

Notice that with this call, we've now created 10 sections as children of this course offering, and the back-end service has automatically generated names (and codes) for them.

**Add a new section after the fact**. Now suppose we want to add an *eleventh* section to this course. First, we need to use a `SectionData` block for the new section's properties:

```
{"Name": "Section 11",
 "Code": "Sec11",
 "Description": {"Content": "New Section Descr.", "Type": "Text} }
```

(*Note*: When you form this block to create the new section you have to use a `RichTextInput` type structure for the `Description` property. When you get the properties for a section back from the service, it writes the description using the `RichText` property instead. This is a common sticky point for devs new to the framework)

Then, you **POST** that block to this route:

```
POST /d2l/api/lp/1.3/113459/sections/
> {"SectionId":113470,
   "Name":"Section 11",
   "Description":{"Text":"Description","Html":""},
   "Enrollments":[]}
```

You'll get back the properties for the newly created section.

**Summary**. So, "why PUT and then POST"? Yes, it is a bit confusing, but think of it this way:

1. The first use, of PUT, is to *update* the "section properties" attribute for a course offering (as a consequence, when a course offering's section properties are initially defined, as a side effect, the back-end creates the section org units needed to go along with those new settings).
2. The second use, of POST, is to *create* a new org unit (a new section), and assign it to the course offering.

Comment: Thank you for the great detail in the explanation.